# How to get height of Screen?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the Height of the device screen that the application is running on.

How would i go about getting just the Height only?

Comment: Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

Answer (score 3):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Height would be in the height variable.

Comment: The getWidth() and getHeight() methods are deprecated starting from SDK Level 13 (Android Honeycomb 3.2): https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/13/changes/android.view.Display.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the DisplayMetrics class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#heightPixels

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```